# Pandas dataframes wont equal each other due to trailing white space being removed

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

**Context**
I have two Pandas dataframes (df1 and df2). One of these is created using the read_csv() method and the other is created using the read_sql() method, n.b. I'm using MySQL and SQL Alchemy core.

The MySql table contains the exact same records as the csv file, yet, whenever I test for equality between them as below, I keep getting a False value.

df1==df2

Upon inspecting the Pandas dataframe comparison report, MySQL table and the csv file I have noticed that the lengths between records vary between the csv file and records in the MySQL database due to differences in trailing white space.

So the question is:

How do I get MySQL to retain trailing whitespaces ?

I have tried changing the column data types to varchar() but seems to not work. Perhaps it has to do with the configuration of MySQL...

Anyway I've spent a day on this problem so thought I'd reach out.

Comment: I would think the other way around, remove the trailing whitespaces in read_csv table with `str.strip()` so you can compare it with the SQL table.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that is something I may resort to. The whitespace, though, has significance on the front end - presentability & readability.